# 302 redirect with query parameters to Microsoft Power BI Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, redirect, aws-lambda, powerbi

I'm using an AWS Lambda function to re-direct requests for a URL in Power BI service using a route mapping in the function to specific reports in Power BI - I do this so that the underlying Power BI URL can be modified while retaining a static URL for end users.  Power BI URL links can change if reports or datasets are modified, hence the need for a static URL.

For example, everything to "customdomain.com" routes to the lambda function; the function then parses the URL's full path and returns a JSON 302 response for re-direct to the actual target URL.

Ex. request to "https://customdomain.com/target_report" returns a 302 response for "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/123/reports/abc"

This has been working fine, but now I'm trying to add query parameter strings to the end of the URL because Power BI can use these to filter reports.

"https://app.powerbi.com/groups/123/reports/abc?filter=table/column%20eq%20'California'"

This raw URL works correctly; however, when I request it in the form of "https://customdomain.com/target_report?filter=table/column%20eq%20'California'" then it is not working.  I can see in the Lambda test that it returns the full URL with the parameters - like follows:

```
{
  "statusCode": 302,
  "headers": {
    "Location": "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/abc/reports/123?filter=table/column%20eq%20'California'"
  }
}
```

But when I check the network routing in Chrome developer tools, the location URL excludes the filter parameter component.

It appears that the browser is stripping the parameters from the re-direct URL being returned in the 302.

Does this seem correct?
Does my Lambda JSON response need to return the parameters under a separate key in the 302 response object?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the networking in AWS - I was using AWS Lambda to perform the re-direct by reading in the URL on the original request coming in and re-directing according to mapping in the function.  First issue was that API gateway was stripping off the query parameters before it was hitting the Lambda function.  Second issue was that the function read the "rawPath" attribute from the request, but this does not contain URL query parameters; the query parameters are contained in the "rawQueryString" attribute instead.